# Where clause not working in LINQ-To-XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My XML file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <root>
    <Message type="sms">
        <Details locale="en" message-type="User.ResetPassword" />
        <Context>
            <Parameter name="Time" value=" 16:03:31" />
            <Parameter name="pswr" value="00" />
            <Parameter name="Date" value="18/12/2014" />
        </Context>
        <Receiver>+923328749199</Receiver>
    </Message>
  </root>
```

My C# code is

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("C:\\Users\\qadeer.hussain\\Desktop\\gw-msg-2.xml");
var name = from nm in xelement.Elements("Message").Elements("Context").Elements("Parameter")
           where nm.Element("Receiver").Value == "+923328749199"
           select nm;
```

Problem is my where clause is not working except where clause query is    working fine. Can you please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: `<Receiver>` is not in `<Parameter>` tag

Comment: so how can i solve this problem?

Comment: See my solution at following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337074/parsing-a-specific-xml-from-api-in-c-sharp/

Comment: It's not even clear what result you're expecting from your query...

Comment: @user1745334; is your question here to receive all parameters?

Answer (score 1):

```
    XElement xelement = XElement.Load("C:\\Users\\qadeer.hussain\\Desktop\\gw-msg-2.xml");
    var name = from nm in xelement.Elements("Message")
               from mm in nm.Elements("Context").Elements("Parameter")  
               where nm.Element("Receiver").Value == "+923328749199"
               select mm;
```

Comment: My guess is OP wants to receive all the parameters, perhaps you should add that part to

Answer (score 0):

`<Receiver>` is not child of `<Parameter>` but child of `<Message>`. Try this way :

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Parse(xml);
var name = from message in xelement.Elements("Message")
           from param in message.Elements("Context").Elements("Parameter")
           where (string)message.Element("Receiver") == "+923328749199"
           select param;
```